# Automatic Foreign key creations

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP.Net Core Framework 3.1 with an Sql server Database.

Here is 2 models i've created:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int child_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And here is what i've add in my dbcontext file:

```
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Childs { get; set; }
```

I have runned:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add Migration1
$ dotnet ef database update
```

It's great, everything works fine.
The Foreign keys have been created in the sql server database.

I have read a book saying i should add this in my dbcontext file:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany(b => b.Childs);
    }
```

what is the goal of this lines ? Is it necessary ?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't the book explain?

Comment: No, this is why i am wondering if this lines are necessary or not

Comment: Some book. Try and see what happens to the data model if you remove the lines.

Comment: This is exactly what i've done and this is why i am asking this question

Comment: The thing is, you're presenting a class model that doesn't have valid primary key properties. When used as such, EF will complain about missing primary keys. With or without this mapping code, this model won't work, which is something you weren't aware of or otherwise had better mentioned. If the keys are mapped properly, the mapping you show won't suffice, so your questions can't be answered.